# Nullspace and different solutions

Tags: matrices

> $\begin{pmatrix}
>      R_{11} & \cdots & R_{1A} \\
>      \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
>      R_{S1} & \cdots & R_{SA} \\
>      1 & \cdots & 1    
>      \end{pmatrix}
> \begin{pmatrix}
> x_1 \\
> \vdots \\
> x_A
> \end{pmatrix}
> =
> \begin{pmatrix}
>      R_{11} & \cdots & R_{1A} \\
>      \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
>      R_{S1} & \cdots & R_{SA} \\
>      1 & \cdots & 1    
>      \end{pmatrix}
> \begin{pmatrix}
> w_1 \\
> \vdots \\
> w_A
> \end{pmatrix}
> \tag1$
>
> Let $\mathcal{R}$ be the $(S+1)\times A$ coefficient matrix in $(1)$. System $(1)$ has solutions $\mathbf{x\neq w}$ if and only if there is a nonzero vector in the nullspace of $\mathcal{R}$.

I can understand the "if" part here, but can't get why "only if " part is true.(That is, why "if system $(1)$ has solutions $\mathbf{x\neq w}$ then there is a nonzero vector in the nullspace of $\mathcal{R}$")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is a solution $x\neq w$, then $R(x-w)=0$ and $x-w\neq 0$.

If there exists $v\neq 0$ with $Rv=0$, then $Rv=R0$ and $(v,0)$ is a solution.